# joining two tables with more connections to the same table in a row

Tags: sql, join

How can i join two tables where the connection to a certain table occurs more than once?

I have these two tables:

```
tableA                         
Name      Value                
================            
Test      001
Car       002
Bike      003

tableB
Num     T1      T2 
====================  
f4b     001     002
aaa     001     003  
666     002     001
```

How can i join these two tables to get:

```
Table A+B 
Num     T1      T2 
====================  
f4b     Test    Car
aaa     Test    Bike  
666     Car     Test
```

If i use

```
SELECT tableB.Num
    ,tableA.NAME
    ,tableA.NAME
FROM tableB
INNER JOIN tableA ON tableB.T1 = tableA.Value
    OR tableB.T2 = tableA.Value
```

i just get the same value in all rows.

Thanks

Comment: "i just get the same value in all rows" is because `tableA.NAME=tableA.NAME`

Comment: @geomagas Yeah, that's true, but he wanted to refference the Name from the `tableA` with both columns in `tableB`, this is what he was probably expecting to happen automatically.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: Yes, that was just a hint. Hints usually make us think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this query:

```
SELECT
  tB.Num 'Num',
  tA1.Name 'T1',
  tA2.Name 'T2'
FROM
  tableB tB INNER JOIN tableA tA1 ON tB.T1 = tA1.Value
            INNER JOIN tableA tA2 ON tB.T2 = tA2.Value
WHERE
  tA1.Value <> tA2.Value
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d5a55/9)** with how it works with sample data you provided.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is what I've been looking for. I also need the combination of 2 same values , but leaving out the the WHERE statement should not be a problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this, but

```
SELECT tableB.Num
    ,tableA.NAME
    ,tableA.NAME
FROM tableB
    ,tableA
WHERE tableB.T1 = tableA.Value
    OR tableB.T2 = tableA.Value
```

Comment: unforunately that does not work. i get every row twice showing the same value for T1 and T2